# Startup python script to re-join layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, attribute-joins

In QGIS 2.2, there is a bug which involves using the **JOINS** properties on a vector layer (that is already being **joined** with several other vector layers) whereby the attributes are not fully loaded.

Example:

```
Result_Layer > Middle_Layer > Layer_1
                            > Layer_2
                            > Layer_3
```

In the above case, the *Result_Layer* will only show the values of its own columns and their respective fields and about a dozen columns coming from the *Middle_Layer* and their respective values before showing **NULL** for the rest of the attribute table.

The number of column and field attributes I am using in total is extensive ( ~200 columns; ~20,000 fields) so I haven't tested this on a much smaller scale.

The workaround at the moment is to **re-join** the *Result_Layer* to the *Middle_Layer*.

---

UPDATE:

I've been looking at refreshing the `mapCanvas()` to see if that would somehow 'rejoin' the layers and bring back the values. I've tried the following in the Python console:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

It probably refreshes but doesn't automatically rejoin. I tried also using `self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` but I get an error.

This is for a client who wants to stick with QGIS 2.2 and does not want to use PostGIS/SpatiaLite as suggested by @mapBaker. Therefore, the only alternative I can think of is to write a script that automatically rejoins all layers when loading up the project.

Also, as a matter of curiosity, is this problem fixed in QGIS 2.4?

Comment: Are you using shapefiles?

Comment: @mapBaker, yes - polygon shapefiles.

Comment: any chance you could load your data into SQLite via QGIS and try these joins out in a relational-database environment?

Comment: @mapBaker, good idea! Although I've never used that before, it's probably best to start learning now as the amount of data will only increase. Many thanks!

Comment: for sure! SQLite will give you the SQL / relational database functions you need to do this stuff much more easily and dynamically... then you'll move into PostGIS and all your problems will be solved!!!

Comment: @mapBaker, one more question please: Should I download any other SQL-related or postGIS-related plugins or is DB Manager all I need to begin with?

Comment: DB Manager should be all you need... keep in touch and let me know what you come up with!

Comment: It still behaves the same in 2.4, but this feature can be expected for 2.6.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasKuhn, I hope this will be implemented in as it's core to my work.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. The question for python sounds like you are trying to automate a (boring) task of boring layers. On the other hand you state that there are NULL values shown in the attribute table but that does implies that you have already done all the joining and it is a bug preventing attributes from showing up properly. Did they ever show up properly and you need to bring them back (you write "bring back the values")?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn, yes all the joining has been done. When loading the project, not all attributes are showing up. They only show up when I re-join the layers. I was thinking if it was possible to automate this re-joining of layers. So in a sense your're right, I would like to "bring back the values".

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Realised I had some outstanding questions which could be answered. You're right in that this problem was fixed way back in QGIS 2.6. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it =)

Comment: @Joseph I don't even remember the details, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in QGIS 2.6 so any recent QGIS version will have this problem solved.